# Is there an eigenvalue of modulus larger than 1?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A\in \operatorname{SL}_d(\mathbb{Z})$ ([the special linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group)) satisfying the two conditions: (1) no eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of unity, (2) the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

> **QUESTION.** Does it follow that at least one eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ fulfills $\vert\lambda\vert>1$? Assuming true, it seems that there must be a theorem of a sort here, but I couldn't recall. It would also be nice if one can relax the conditions to gain the same conclusion, if possible.

**UPDATE.** After exploring papers by Kronecker (thanks [Terry Tao](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415863/is-there-an-eigenvalue-of-modulus-larger-than-1#comment1066826_415863)) and others, I realized that we don't quite need "irreducibility" but "monic" is enough.

Comment: Can't we simply say that the product of eigenvalues equals 1 (if we are considering modulus)?

Comment: @richrow the point is to discard eigenvalues in the unit circle such as $(3+4i)/5$ (which is not a root of unity). In particular the conclusion is false if $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$ is replaced with $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Q})$.

Comment: @YCor Indeed, now it makes sense.

Comment: This is a result of Kronecker. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10911/english-reference-for-a-result-of-kronecker

Comment: @TerryTao: that is what I thought! It can't be new, although I appreciate the work below.

Comment: The result is false with "monic" unless the polynomial 1 is excluded :) alternatively one can assume that $A$ is not virtually unipotent (i.e., no power of $A$ has characteristic polynomial $(X-1)^d$). But in any case boiling down to the irreducible case is straightforward.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the characteristic polynomial is irreducible, eigenvalues are simple and hence the matrix is $\mathbf{C}$-diagonalizable. If all were on the unit cercle, it would follow that $\{ A^n:n\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ is bounded. But since it is contained in the set of integral points, this would force it to be finite, and hence all eigenvalues would be roots of unity, contradiction.

Hence one is not on the unit circle. Since the product of eigenvalues is $\pm 1$ (the determinant), it follows that some eigenvalue has modulus $>1$.

---

PS: Here's the straightforward way to extend this the general case (without irreducibility). Let $A\in\mathrm{M}_d(\mathbf{Z})$ be a matrix whose eigenvalues are not only among $0$ and roots of unity. As any integral matrix, we can block-triangulate it (over $\mathbf{Z}$) so that all diagonal blocks are $\mathbf{Q}$-irreducible. Hence at least one diagonal block, with characteristic polynomial $P=P(t)$, also satisfies the assumption. So $P$ is $\mathbf{Q}$-irreducible, and not equal to $t$. If $|P(0)|\ge 2$ then clearly some root has modulus $>1$. Otherwise, $P(0)\in\{\pm 1\}$ and we are in the previous (main) case.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan this is a subset of the $d^2$-dimensional space $M_d(\mathbf{C})$ of complex matrices.

Comment: "bounded" in a finite-dimensional vector space is a perfectly well-defined notion.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan this is really ultra standard. Yes, it means that all matrix entries are bounded.

Comment: @YCor: I know you are clear about your points, I just want readers to follow as well. Thanks for the input, too.

Comment: Using the companion matrix, this gives a nice alternative proof of Kronecker's theorem (the strategy being the same).

Comment: By the way, for context, there exists matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_4(\mathbf{Z})$ whose characteristic polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$ but has roots of modulus 1. Indeed $(X^2+(1+\sqrt{2})X+1)(X^2+(1-\sqrt{2})X+1)$ is such a polynomial.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Strictly speaking, Kronecker's theorem is a little stronger in that it also treats (with appropriate modifications to the statement) the case of matrices of determinant other than 1, and in particular non-invertible matrices, though probably some variant of YCor's argument will extend to these cases also.

Comment: @TerryTao if I'm correct, one easily reduces to the irreducible case, and then the result is trivial in the case the determinant is not $\neq 1$ (if $0$ then the characteristic polynomial is then $X$, and otherwise the determinant has modulus $\ge 2$ which is clearly impossible)

Comment: @TerryTao The determinant can also be $-1$, but I think YCor's argument extends to the case of the group $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I think the arguments are not so different. Kronecker's argument demonstrates that there are only finitely many monic integer polynomials of degree $d$ with all roots on the unit circle. Hence if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ above, then there are only finitely many possibilities for $\lambda^{n}$ , as these are eigenvalues of powers of $A$, so roots of monic degree $d$ integer polynomials. Hence $\lambda$ is a root of unity.  Also Kronecker  does not need irreducibility, and works when $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson irreducibility is an immediate reduction. I've added the argument.

Comment: I agree that one can reduce to that, but Kronecker's argument doesn't need that reduction, it's just as valid for indecomposable matrices.

Comment: Sure; that indeed makes a difference between the arguments. The boundedness of $\{A^n:n\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ would fail for $A$ non-semisimple.